# What is the proper value representation of a schema.org/polygon when used in JSON-LD?

Tags: json, rest, schema.org, linked-data, json-ld

The data representation I will try to use for a RESTful API is **JSON-LD** and the vocabulary I intend to use are those from **schema.org**.

In the vocabulary [schema.org/GeoShape](http://schema.org/GeoShape), it says that polygons are expected to be on text format but it doesn't exactly say what kind of text format. It wasn't also stated that it should use the [WKT Polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Geometric_objects) format.

**WKT Polygon Format** *(Well-known Text)*

> POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))

However, since I will be representing data using JSON-LD, it may also be reasonable to use something similar with GeoJson Polygons or the native JSON Array.

**GeoJson Polygon Format**

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
        [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
    ]
}
```

**Native JSON 2D Array**

```
[
[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
]
```

With this in mind, what is the proper value representation of a [schema.org/polygon](http://schema.org/polygon) when used in JSON-LD?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to use the suggested text format as that's what most consumers will expect. If you prefer a more structured representation, you could consider using GeoJSON-LD instead: http://geojson.org/vocab

Comment: cool! so that would be like

`{
"@context" : "http://geojson.org/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld",
"@type" : "Polygon",
"coordinates",  [
   [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0],[100.0, 0.0] ]
   ]
}`

Comment: I tried that [GeoJSON Vocabulary](http://geojson.org/vocab) and tested the response text in [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). It turns out both *longitude* and *latitude* values will be interpreted as [http://example.com/vocab#coordinates](http://example.com/vocab#coordinates)

Comment: Which isn't surprising if you look at how http://geojson.org/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld is defined. It contains the following mapping: `"coordinates": "http://example.com/vocab#coordinates"`

Answer (score 0):

the following snippet works for me in the Google testing tool https://search.google.com/test/rich-results and the Schema.org testing tool https://validator.schema.org/

```
"@type": "GeoShape",
        "polygon": "[GeoPoint1],[GeoPoint2],[GeoPoint3],[GeoPoint4],[GeoPoint1]"
```